# Android RTSP - MediaPlayer init failure / PVMFFailure

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp

I have a camera by Cisco and like to stream it's video stream to my android phone.
It's coded in MPEG4 so there should be no problem, but it's not working anymore (it worked with another camera a few weeks ago). Any idea what I might try ? I don't know what's wrong here.

```
I/ActivityManager(   79): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.Projekt1/.CameraView }
I/System.out(18792): SDPURL - rtsp://10.42.0.103:554/live.sdp
I/NotificationService(   79): enqueueToast pkg=com.Projekt1 callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@44a22218 duration=0
D/MediaPlayer(18792): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
I/ActivityManager(   79): Displayed activity com.Projekt1/.CameraView: 270 ms (total 270 ms)
W/MediaPlayer(18792): info/warning (1, 26)
I/MediaPlayer(18792): Info (1,26)
E/PlayerDriver(   52): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
E/MediaPlayer(18792): error (1, -1)
E/MediaPlayer(18792): Error (1,-1)
D/VideoView(18792): Error: 1,-1
W/PlayerDriver(   52): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Nils you have the right codec but Android supports only .3gp Streaming for video, i see you have

```
rtsp://10.42.0.103:554/live.sdp
```

Comment: mhh ... really? That's strange. The VC220, a camera by Cisco, is working with exactly that string. In the preferences it's set to MPEG4 ... only the others cameras by Cisco have problems, but deliver me the same string with UPnP ...