# Android MediaPlayer error (1,-1)?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I'm trying to play my video in Samsung Galaxy S but its not working..
my video is uploaded on a server and when I play it on my emulator it works fine but of 
course slow, but when I play it on my device it gives me Sorry, this video cannot be played with the following error:

```
01-06 14:37:41.730: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1284): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure

01-06 14:37:41.730: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4585): error (1, -1)

01-06 14:37:41.730: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4585): Error (1,-1)
```

my link looks like this: http://user---.---.--.--/-------/try.mp4

this link works fine whether in emulator or device: http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp

I'm sure its not a codec error because I tried playing in from sdcard/try.mp4 and it worked fine

Comment: Android supports only ".3gp" for video streaming.<br>SOURCE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056383/android-rtsp-mediaplayer-init-failure-pvmffailure

Comment: Thanks but how come it works in the emulator?

Comment: Never trust android emulator, unlike iOS. Try on device and judge.

Comment: thats my problem..on device its not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support .mp4 files for streaming.You can play .mp4 from SDCard.

Comment: I played this mp4 video on android device but other is not working 
http://i250.photobucket.com/download-albums/gg264/APT08/APTAd3.mp4

Answer (score 0):

for the public interest: if your file is delivered through a php file, which runs unter php5 and your headers are not set correctly, php5 automatically sends a 500 http header!! this maybe also the problem (so was at mine)