# RTSP and Android, finally what is supported today?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to make an application reading video streams from an ip camera with RTSP. I have the following URL :

rtsp://x.x.x.x:554/user=aaa&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?

And when I try to open this url using MediaPlayer, according many samples found on the web and stackoverflow, I get the following error :

couldn't open file on client side, trying on server side

I precise that I tried to open video stored on the sdcard with the same code, and it worked well. I just used setVideoPath instead of setVideoUri

```
String uriToParse = rtspPath;
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriToParse));
myVideoView.start();
```

So my question is : according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056383/android-rtsp-mediaplayer-init-failure-pvmffailure), what is the best solution to do now if I want to continue with RTSP ?

Comment: You could use VLC on Android.

Comment: Yes this is an option I had considered. I already have downloaded vlc source code and I'm trying to understand how it works. As I don't need all the functionnalities and that I want to customize it, it takes some time. But well, if there is no other solution I'm gonna do this. Thanks for your confirmation !